# is it compulsory to perform Rafa Yadain

Tags: salat

Please tell me the answer that is rafa yadain after before Ruku and after it  is compulsory if yes then why? if no then why?
Please answer with proves

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE, the Q&A site about Islam. We strongly recommend you to take a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) to familiarise with what Islam SE is about and visit the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help) to learn about the stack exchange model.

Comment: Anything which is compulsory can be found in the Quran, with a few exceptions hadith only provide optional or recommanded acts.

Answer (score 1):

### According to Imam Hanbal and Imam Shafee, it is mustahabb to perform Rafa Yadain whilst saying Allahu Akbar before bowing in Ruku

---

There are hadiths that prove that the Prophet Muhammad perform Rafa Yadain before Ruku.

> ‘Abd-Allaah ibn ‘Umar (may Allaah be pleased with them both), said that the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) used to raise his hands to shoulder level when he started to pray, when he said “Allaahu akbar” before bowing in rukoo’, and when he raised his head from rukoo’.
>
> [Narrated by al-Bukhaari (735) and Muslim (390)]

The majority of scholars said that it is **mustahabb** for the worshipper to raise his hands at the points mentioned in the hadeeth.

Imaam al-Bukhaari (may Allaah have mercy on him) wrote a book on this issue which he called Juz’ fi Raf’ al-Yadayn (Section on Raising the Hands), in which he proved that the hands should be raised at these two points on the prayer, and he strongly denounced those who go against that.

He narrated that al-Hasan said:

> “The Companions of the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) used to raise their hands during prayer when they bowed and when they stood up (from bowing).” Al-Bukhaari said, “Al-Hasan did not exclude any of the Sahaabah from that, and it was not proven that any one among the Sahaabah did not raise his hands.”
>
> [al-Majmoo’ by al-Nawawi, 3/399-406]

This is the view of the Hanbalis and the Shafi'is.
We don't know whether or no Imam Abu Haneefah reached the hadith but his followers did but they did not follow this and only performed Rafa Yadain at the start of Salah. They used the following hadith to support this:

> Ibn Mas’ood [radhiallaahu anhu] says, ‘I shall show you how Nabi [sallallaahu alayhi wasallam] performed Salaat and he only made Raf-ul yadayn in the beginning of Salaat.’
>
> (Sunan al-Tirmidhi Hadith 257)

Based on this, Imaam Abu Hanifa and Imaam Maalik [ra] preferred this view that one should only raise his hands in the beginning of Salaat at the Takbeer Tahrima.

See (Naylul Awtaar vol.2 pg.185; Ilmiyah)

However, all the Imaams consider both views – to life the hands in all positions or only in the beginning as permissible.** According to Imaam Abu Hanifa and Imaam Maalik, it is also **permissible** to lift the hands in all postions. According to Imaam al-Shaafi’ee and Imaam Ahmad ibn Hanbal, it is **not compulsory** to lift the hands in all postions.

And Allah knows best.

---

Source: [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/21439) and [Islam Q&A-Hanafi](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/askimam/18114)